# Connection refused while web scraping using HTMLUnit

Tags: connection, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am trying to build a java application to scrape a website using HTMLUnit. After extracting some data the application encounters following exception -
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to siteURL refused.

If I run application again, it is able to extract some data again before failing with the same exception. Probably the server see lot of requests from same client IP and refuses connection for a request.

Also, when application encounters this problem, I am able to connect to the site using a browser.

How can I overcome this problem? In web scraping applications how are such problems approached and resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I debug such issues :

Download [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler)

By default, fiddler listens on port 8888, all you have to do, is configure webClient to use fiddler as proxy & then all requests being sent can be seen (analyzed, modified & re-sent too) in fiddler.

```
    client.getOptions().setProxyConfig(new ProxyConfig("127.0.0.1", 8888));
```

From what I can say from my previous experience is that the target site blocks after some-time, you can try adding a pause or rotating proxies & user-agents. You can also try clearing cookies.